# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I know this question has asked before, but I want to ask it with respect to Unity.So I am trying to make my game target API level 33 as per the new googlePlay store policy. But I got many errors and finally stuck with the following error ad can't proceed further

> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused,
> use --status for details
>
> Configure project : Build was configured to prefer settings
> repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was
> added by build file 'build.gradle'
>
> 0x00007ff73ead332d (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
> 0x00007ff73ead82d9 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
> 0x00007ff73faa7be1 (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x00007ff740166072 (Unity)
> DebugStringToFile 0x00007ff73d9fcae6 (Unity)
> DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x0000019c51814ae3 (Mono JIT Code)
> (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log
> (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
> 0x0000019c51814a1b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat
> (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
> 0x0000019c518147a0 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log
> (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 0x0000019c51814665 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 0x0000019cd412449b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.Android.GradleInvokationException:ParseAndShowException ()
> 0x0000019cdcb19ba3 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks
> (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext)
> 0x0000019cdec2f203 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
> 0x0000019cdea7a293 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
> 0x0000019cdea79990 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess
> (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
> 0x0000019cdea79cf5 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke)
> :runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object
> (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007ffd2015e274 (mono-2.0-bdwgc)
> mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
> 0x00007ffd2009eb74 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3066)
> 0x00007ffd2009ed0c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3113)
> 0x00007ff73e9ea824 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007ff73e9c8944
> (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff7404dbcb1 (Unity)
> CallMono 0x00007ff7404e4b67 (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
> 0x00007ff7404def53 (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild 0x00007ff7404dd04e
> (Unity) DoBuildPlayer 0x00007ff7404d0875 (Unity) BuildPlayer
> 0x00007ff73e2666cf (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
> 0x00007ff73dfb573c (Unity)
> BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck 0x0000019cdc99fc37
> (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native)
> UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
> (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
> 0x0000019cdc99f403 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer
> (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) 0x0000019cdc99b9bb (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods
> (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 0x0000019c7f4c5613 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons
> (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
> 0x0000019c7f3f221b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
> 0x0000019c5f3d0dbb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI
> () 0x0000019c54aa15e2 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI
> (UnityEngine.Rect) 0x0000019c54aa1403 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect) 0x0000019c54a92103
> (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI () 0x0000019c549ece2f
> (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI
> (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
> 0x0000019cd5a4effb (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent
> (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
> 0x0000019c5dd1091b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent
> (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool) 0x0000019c5dd107a3 (Mono JIT
> Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent
> (UnityEngine.Event,bool) 0x0000019c7f5a62ab (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool) 0x0000019c7f5a39e3 (Mono
> JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool) 0x0000019c4e5da5a3 (Mono
> JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ProcessEvent
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x0000019c4e5da183 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEvent
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x0000019c4e5d9ebf (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x0000019c4e5d9c53 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x0000019c7f5a0deb (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
> 0x0000019c4e5ffb6e (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
> 0x0000019c4e5ff50b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
> 0x0000019c4e5d0963 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
> 0x0000019c4e5d07f3 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate () 0x0000019c4e5d074b
> (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
> 0x0000019c4e5ff9cb (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
> 0x0000019c4e5faa23 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
> 0x0000019c4e5fa89b (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
> 0x0000019c5181aa73 (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch
> (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel) 0x0000019c5181a3a3
> (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent
> (int,intptr,bool&) 0x0000019c5181a1bf (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
> 0x0000019c5181a0fb (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2
> (int,intptr) 0x0000019c51819f5d (Mono JIT Code)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
> 0x0000019c5181a016 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke)
> :runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
> 0x00007ffd2015e274 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
> 0x00007ffd2009eb74 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3066)
> 0x00007ffd2009ed0c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at
> C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3113)
> 0x00007ff73e9ea824 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007ff73e9c8944
> (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff73e9c3595 (Unity)
> ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff73eb1ddda (Unity)
> Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
> 0x00007ff73f510c28 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
> 0x00007ff73fadab8e (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent 0x00007ff73f510b73
> (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEventFromAPI 0x00007ff73f510a48 (Unity)
> GUIView::ProcessInputEvent 0x00007ff73fadb9be (Unity)
> GUIView::ProcessEventMessages 0x00007ff73fad5745 (Unity)
> GUIView::GUIViewWndProc 0x00007ffd797fe858 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
> 0x00007ffd797fe299 (USER32) DispatchMessageW 0x00007ff73faae3a3
> (Unity) MainMessageLoop 0x00007ff73fab3d80 (Unity) WinMain
> 0x00007ff740e97fee (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh 0x00007ffd79c17344
> (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007ffd7a9a26b1 (ntdll)
> RtlUserThreadStart

I did many things before reaching this point which I will explain below.

First I updated my project from Unity 2021.2.5f1 to Unity 2022.3.9f1 and set the target API level to 33 and built it. I got some errors saying deprecated gradle was used which was incompatible with gradle 8.0 .

2)I then in the gradleTemplate.properties file added the following line

```
org.gradle.warning.mode=all
```

and then I set the stacktrace to full and I got the following error

[image: Error]

3)Then I saw some video on youtube and did the following changes:

In baseProjectTemplate.gradle file replaced jcenter() with mavencentral()
In the same file above removed google() from repositories section and flatDir { dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs" }

4)From settingsTemplate.gradle

removed flatDir { dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs" }

I tried to delete the library and reopened Unity and tried everthing including this answer, but nothing is happening . I am stuck in this issue for 3 days and really fed up with everything .Anyone can help me please.......

Comment: Can you see if you have `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)` in your settings.gradle? If so, move all repository declarations to settings.gradle from other gradle files

Comment: hi @ben_joseph thanks for the reply. I have repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS) in my settingsTemplate.gradle file. What to do know?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution finally after a lot of searching for days. The solution was to delete all plugins files in the folder : "C:...ProjectName\Assets\Plugins\Android", then build succeeded. Thanks to the guy who commented on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efzqmYqyJsM&ab_channel=Hmk-Solution) . Hope this helps someone struggling out there